# How to define the same names from one sheet to other sheets in the same workbook?

Tags: excel, names, defined

I created a form on an Excel sheet where I defined names (not in contiguous cells), the defined names already entered on the "Source" form like

```
Name: zzz xxx  
Address: 456 mmm dddd  
Number: 123456  
Date: 20-Dec-2019
```

I want to define the same names on other existing forms on other sheets that do not have names defined.

Then, I need to combine all data from all sheets copied to a new sheet and all data collected from all sheets to be in a table with data in columns and rows like this

```
Name     Address        Number  Date  
zzz xxx  456 mmm dddd   123456  20-Dec-2019   
tyr utr  677 gjgjh      765768  30-Nov-2018
```

Thanks for the support and advice.